# How to order coordinates with Mongoengine?

Tags: python, geojson, mongoengine

I'm working with Django and Mongoengine, I use GeoJson coordinates and I have to sort a coordinate list closest to the farthest, I have a starting point but I want to know if mongoengine can order those coordinates and what is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `near` for that query:

```
loc.objects(point__near=[40, 5])
```

[docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=geojson#geo-queries)